# How to bulk add/check paths to Eclipse resource working set?

Tags: eclipse, working-set

I'm currently in a process of re-creating a resource working set in Eclipse, which would include ~130 projects.
But as I'm setting a *resource* working set, I don't let the projects checked, but instead only let relevant folders and files checked, i.e. pom.xml + /src folder + /target/generated-* folders.

Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

In ***Window > Preferences: Oomph > Dynamic Working Set*** you can specify a working set based on repository location or name patterns.

See [Eclipse Wiki - *Dynamic Working Sets*](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Dynamic_Working_Sets) for details.

Comment: Interesting - although the so-called User Manual is so succinct - but this feature builds up Java working sets, not resource-based ones.